# Why tod package's fuerte page instructions using diamondback pakcages?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [tod](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tod) doc.

I change to fuerte tag.

Which tod.install contain many diamondback packages.

```
  - other: {local-name: /opt/ros/diamondback/ros}
  - other: {local-name: /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks}
  - svn: {local-name: vslam, uri: 'https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/vslam/trunk'}
  - svn: {local-name: vision_bleeding, uri: 'https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding'}
  - svn: {local-name: object_recognition, uri: 'https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_diamondback/stacks/object_recognition'}
  - svn: {local-name: object_recognition_experimental, uri: 'https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_diamondback/stacks/object_recognition_experimental'}
```

How to fix it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46957/why-tod-package%27s-fuerte-page-instructions-using-diamondback-pakcages?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-10-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you face an inconsistency in the wiki, caused by a recent change of the wiki infrastructure and indexer. It probably never has been ported to fuerte. You can try to compile it from source, but I would expect a lot of problems because of changed interfaces, updates to pcl and deprecated packages.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0